# How to append new comment to the already existing comment on JIRA using Java

Tags: java, jira

I need to append a new comment to an already existing comment in JIRA using its comment ID in Java. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I'm tempted to post an answer "Yes" (but its not a valid answer, 30 characters are minimum).

Comment: Can you just provide the piece of java code to do this

Comment: Can you confirm that you can't find the ability to do this in the JIRA API documentation? https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/jira/latest/reference/packages.html

Comment: Ooh, I found it! https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/issue/comments/CommentManager.html#update-com.atlassian.jira.issue.comments.Comment-boolean-

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get the existing comment and update it?

```
1. GET /rest/api/2/issue/{issue}/comment/{id}
```

then update

```
2. POST /rest/api/2/issue/{issue}/comment/{id}
```

Check notes [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/updating-an-issue-via-the-jira-rest-apis) in Jira documentation.

> Some fields cannot be updated this way (for example, comments).
>   Instead you must use explicit-verb updates (see below). You can tell
>   if a field cannot be implicitly set by the fact it doesn't have a SET
>   verb.
>
> EDIT: Edits an element in a field that is an array. The element is
>   indexed/identified by the value itself (usually by id/name/key).
>
> ```
> edit the text of a particular comment:
> ```

```
{ "update": { "comments": [{"edit": {"id": 10002, "body": "newbody"} } ] } }
```

Comment: can we perform the same operations using jira client?